# Macros VBA XML error

Tags: xml, vba, api

I have a problem and I can't resolve it, I just try a lot of things but without success. I'll show you my problem.

I want to get the value of a node of XML file but I have the error

> Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

```
 Private Sub teste()

Dim strPath As String
Dim dblRate As Double
Dim xmlOBject As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xmlOBject = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
'website path
strPath = "http://localhost/laravel%2013062017/laravel/public/admin/apiNoticia"
xmlOBject.async = False
xmlOBject.Load (strPath)
'get the exchange rate value
dblRate = xmlOBject.ChildNodes.Item(2).ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Item(2).ChildNodes.Item(1).nodeTypedValue
End Sub
```

My XML:

```
<root>
<row_0>
<id>1</id>
<titulo>1ºNoticia</titulo>
<image>nullo</image>
<conteudo>gtrtgrtgtrg</conteudo>
<created_at>2017-06-29 16:30:27</created_at>
<updated_at>2017-06-29 16:30:27</updated_at>
</row_0>
<row_1>
<id>2</id>
<titulo>Teste2</titulo>
<image>nullo</image>
<conteudo>rreerre</conteudo>
<created_at>2017-07-03 10:21:07</created_at>
<updated_at>2017-07-03 10:21:07</updated_at>
</row_1>
<row_2>
<id>3</id>
<titulo>ggrttrg</titulo>
<image>nullo</image>
<conteudo>tgrtgtrg</conteudo>
<created_at>2017-07-03 11:26:04</created_at>
<updated_at>2017-07-03 11:26:04</updated_at>
</row_2>
</root>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Where in your XML is the *exchange rate value*?

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

a) Using your XML, the load fails with invalid char in line 4 - the `º`. Check the result of the `load`-command:

```
if not xmlOBject.Load (strPath) then
    MsgBox("Load failed")
    exit Sub
end if
```

b) The index of the nodes starts with 0, not 1. Furthermore, the first list of nodes `<root>` has only one entry.

c) Fetching the dbl-Rate, you access data from four levels, but your data has only 3 level.

d) You try to read a Double-Value but there is no in your example XML.

The following code accesses the string `Teste2`, you can figure out from there how to get the data you need (there is no need to use the `item`-property)

```
Dim v as variant
v = xmlOBject.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(1).nodeTypedValue
Debug.Print v
```

Comment: i just check mt XML Load and you´re right, theres an error. do you know what could be the error?

Comment: i just found it and fix it in xml but i continue with rhe same error